# Traer objecto JSON de MYSQL con PHP

Tags: php, mysql, json, base-de-datos, webservice

que tal ando elaborando un webservices para consumirlo con android sin embargo no tengo  idea como convertir un consulta de mysql específicamente traer la consulta que es un JSON y convertirlo a otro objeto JSON

lo que tengo de codigo en PHP es estoy

```html
<?php


$server = "localhost";
$user = "root";
$pass = "";
$bd = "ecommerce";

//Creamos la conexión
$conexion = mysqli_connect($server, $user, $pass,$bd) 
or die("Ha sucedido un error inexperado en la conexion de la base de datos");

//generamos la consulta
$sql = "select * from productos order by id desc limit 10";
mysqli_set_charset($conexion, "utf8"); //formato de datos utf8

if(!$result = mysqli_query($conexion, $sql)) die();

$clientes = array(); //creamos un array

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) 
{ 
    $id=$row['id'];
    $nombre=$row['titulo'];
    $multimedia=$row['multimedia'];
    
    

    $clientes[] = array(
    'id'=> $id, 
    'titulo'=> $nombre
    ,'multimedia'=> $multimedia    
    );

}
    
//desconectamos la base de datos
$close = mysqli_close($conexion) 
or die("Ha sucedido un error inexperado en la desconexion de la base de datos");
  

//Creamos el JSON
header('Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf8');
$json_string = json_encode($clientes);
echo $json_string;



?>
```

y el resultado que me trae es el siguiente

```html
[
{
"id": "501",
"titulo": "Computadora Gamer",
"multimedia": "[{\"foto\":\"vistas/img/multimedia/computadora-gamer/refOver_Voxel.jpg\"},{\"foto\":\"vistas/img/multimedia/computadora-gamer/refOver_Voxel.jpg\"},{\"foto\":\"vistas/img/multimedia/computadora-gamer/voxelart1.1.png\"},{\"foto\":\"vistas/img/multimedia/computadora-gamer/voxelart2.1.png\"},{\"foto\":\"vistas/img/multimedia/computadora-gamer/voxelart2.1.png\"}]"
},
{
"id": "500",
"titulo": "Curso de Bootstrap",
"multimedia": "N4aY6yX-MaM"
},
{
"id": "499",
"titulo": "Curso de canvas y Javascript",
"multimedia": "N4aY6yX-MaM"
}
]
```

ahora en donde dice multimedia viene otro objeto y es donde no encuentro como acceder a el para convertirlo a formato JSON

espero que me ayuden chicos :)

Comment: Puedes usar `json_decode` $clients = json_decode($clientes); json_encode($clients["multimedia"]);

Comment: Primeramente en ninguno de los casos estás ante un Objeto JSON, sino ante un Array JSON. Son dos cosas distintas y tienen tratos distintos. Es un Array porque empieza por `[` y termina por `]`. Tampoco se entiende bien si te interesa el array JSON que hay en la 1ª clave `multimedia` ¿? además tus datos no son regulares (en unos casos la clave `multimedia` es un Array JSON, en otros es una cadena). Eso es inquietante en este tipo de diseños porque podría hacer que la app haga crash en ciertos casos. Por lo general en un JSON cada clave tiene el mismo tipo de contenido, no diversos tipos.